# Adding extra lines with same structure with grep (or something like that)

Tags: grep, code-duplication

I'm trying to write in every file I found a word, lets say I have

```
>>grep one ~/home/docs/*
/numbers.txt one is a number
/integers.txt one is an integer
```

and I need to append an extra line just below which says almost the same, but with the number two instead, say

> "After some coding where i can append the second line (...)"

I should be able to write

```
>>grep two ~/home/docs/*
/numbers.txt two is a number
/integers.txt two is an integer
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be divided in 3 steps :

1. Find all the files that contains the keyword ex: one

   fgrep -l one *
2. iterate through all the files listed in first step using for loop

   for file in $(grep -l one * ) ; do ; done
3. perform a operation on every iteration , append a custom line to the said file

   for file in $( grep -l one *); do echo "found one in this file so adding this customer line " >> $file ; done

So as mentioned in point 3 , the final command would be

```
for file in $( grep -l one *); do sed -i 's/one/two/g' $file ;echo "found one in this file so replacing it with two " >> $file ; done
```

Comment: Thanks, it really works. But i still having the need of copying the previous line and changing the element one by two

Comment: @ErickMunive i have edited my answer to replace 'one' with 'two' and kept the echo statement as well to append the file with your custom string.